# python string evaluation not giving proper output

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a  python function test to test my code . ' got and expected string are the same , But when I check it through the below method it gives X instead of OK

Edit : including the parent function and invocation also

```
def donuts(count):
  if count <=10 :
    print 'Number of donuts:',count
  else :
    print 'Number of donuts: many'
    return 

def test(got, expected):
    if got == expected:
       prefix = ' OK '
    else:
       prefix = '  X '
       print '%s got: %s expected: %s'  % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected))
       return
```

where both got and expected looks same to me , Am I missing something ?
Removed the O/p as it was misleading :
Function Declared like this :

```
test(donuts("11"), "Number of donuts: many")
```

Comment: Use `print repr(got), repr(expected)` to see what the differences could be. Clearly, they are *not* the same.

Comment: Also, that `return` statement does literally nothing.

Comment: Also try type(got) and type(expected).

Comment: That can't be the output from your code.  One has `:`, one has `=`, and the `repr()` output should have some kind of quotation mark.

Comment: Your sample output does seem likely given that you already seem to be using `repr()` calls, and assuming that `got` and `expected` are strings. Unless you have custom types with custom `__repr__` methods, your output is missing quotes and there should *not* be a  newline. That is not even mentioning the fact that your code prints `got:`, but your sample output has `got =`.

Comment: test for white space.. Although they may look the same, one could contain an extra " " at the end or something of the ilk.

Comment: it may also be an issue that you aren't getting strings.. after reading your code, you may want to add a str(got) == str(expected) because it looks like those might not be strings.  What do you see as their value in a debugger?

Comment: @Lattyware - This is a code from google and they chose to have the return as part of all function templates. It basically doesnt return anything I guess

Comment: @Rusty Weber - I have tried str() already and got same results

Comment: @DSM - Not Necessarily

Comment: @sudeepmathew `return` without an expression after it just does `return None`, which is what Python will `return` if there isn't a return statement. Given this is at the end of your function, it's completely redundant.

Comment: The point of what DSM and the guys above are saying is that you need to work out what `got` and `expected` are, and why they are not testing as equal. The output you have given and the code you are giving us do not match up. Please run the *actual* code posted here, and copy/paste the output. Otherwise, we can't possibly help. If you know what type `got` and `expected` are, and it's user-defined, also give us the definition of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`donuts("11")` will print `"Number of donuts: many"` but it returns `None`.

`test(donuts("11"), "Number of donuts: many")` is comparing `None` and `"Number of donuts: many"` which are not equal.  If you wanted to make this code work then change your `donuts()` function to this:

```
def donuts(count):
  if count <=10 :
    return 'Number of donuts: %s' % count
  else :
    return 'Number of donuts: many'
```

Also there is an indentation bug in your `test()` function causing the print to only run on the else condition.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the indentation bug in test may be print the function with proper indentation ?

Comment: See how your 'print' function appeared directly below 'prefix = " X "'? This means it will run in the same block as the prefix line which in this case is the else: block. Python uses indentation the same way C tyle languages (like Java and PHP) use {}